# Python list initialization using multiple range statements

Tags: python, list, initialization, range

I want one long list, say [1,2,3,4,5,15,16,17,18,19] as an example.  To initialize this, I try typing:

```
new_list = [range(1,6),range(15,20)]
```

However this doesn't do what I want, returning:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

When I do:

```
len(new_list)
```

It returns 2, instead of the 10 elements I wanted (since it made 2 lists inside the list).  Obviously in this example I could just type out what I want, but I'm trying to do this for some odd iterated lists that go like:

```
new_list = [range(101,6284),8001,8003,8010,range(10000,12322)]
```

Desiring a 1-D list instead of a list of lists (or whatever it's best called).  I'm guessing this is really easy and I'm missing it, but after quite a bit of searching I've come up with nothing too useful.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this for Python 2.x:

```
 range(1,6) + range(15,20)
```

Or if you're using Python3.x, try this:

```
list(range(1,6)) + list(range(15,20))
```

For dealing with elements in-between, for Python 2.x:

```
range(101,6284) + [8001,8003,8010] + range(10000,12322)
```

And finally for dealing with elements in-between, for Python 3.x:

```
list(range(101,6284)) + [8001,8003,8010] + list(range(10000,12322))
```

The key aspects to remember here is that in Python 2.x `range` returns a list and in Python 3.x it returns an iterable (so it needs to be explicitly converted to a list). And that for appending together lists, you can use the `+` operator.

Comment: Is there any easy way to insert single numbers in between, all in one line?  I'm guessing I could append each one, but there's quite few sporadically spaced between list statements, thanks for the help.

Comment: @jackd  updated my answer. Just pack them in a single-element list, like so: `range(1,3) + [3] + range(4,6)`

Comment: You already got it, I was just too slow to notice, thanks this is exactly what I needed.  Simple, just couldn't find the right keyword search to land on the answer!

Answer (score 9):

You can use [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten the output of your `range()` calls.

```
import itertools
new_list = list(itertools.chain(xrange(1,6), xrange(15,20)))
```

Using `xrange` (or simply `range()` for python3) to get an iterable and chaining them together means only one list object gets created (no intermediate lists required).

If you need to insert intermediate values, just include a list/tuple in the chain:

```
new_list = list(itertools.chain((-3,-1), 
                                xrange(1,6), 
                                tuple(7),  # make single element iterable
                                xrange(15,20)))
```

Comment: To include a single value, make sure it's a single item in an iterable, e.g. `tuple(8001)` or `[8001]` or `list(8001)`, otherwise it will add `8`, `0`, `0`, and `1`.

Answer (score 3):

`range` returns a list to begin with, so you need to either concatenate them together with `+` or use `append()` or `extend()`.

```
new_list = range(1,6) + range(15,20)
```

or

```
new_list = range(101,6284)
mew_list.extend([8001,8003,8010])
mew_list.extend(range(10000,12322))
```

Alternatively, you could use `itertools.chain()` as shown in Shawn Chin's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just unpack the `range` values as follows:

```
new_list = [*range(1,6), *range(15,20)]

print(new_list)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

print(len(new_list))
# 10

print(type(new_list))
# <class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain

new_list = [x for x in chain(range(1,6), range(15,20))]
print new_list
```

Output like you wanted:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

i would like to propose u a version without +

```
import operator
a = list(range(1,6))
b = list(range(7,9))
print(operator.concat(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just unpack range values as follows:

```
>>> new_list = [*range(1,6),*range(15,20)]
>>> new_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> len(new_list)
10
```

Comment: Please don't post another answer to update your existing answer. Just use the [edit] button. After you have already posted [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63873825/13865476), I would recommend deleting this one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) function and unpacking operator (*) for it

Example 1:

```
from itertools import chain

output = [*chain(range(1, 6), range(15, 20))]
```

Example 2:

```
from itertools import chain

data = [range(1, 6), range(15, 20)]
output = [*chain(*data)]
```

Example 3 using [chain.fromiterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
data = [range(1, 6), range(15, 20)]
output = [*chain.from_iterable(data)]
```

output

```
assert output == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```