# Python: How to range() multiple values from list or dictionary?

Tags: python, range

Im new to programming. Trying to range numbers - For example if i want to range more than one range, 1..10  20...30  50...100. Where i need to store them(list or dictionary) and how to use them one by one?

```
example = range(1,10)
exaple2 = range(20,30)

for b in example:
    print b
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959510/python-list-initialization-using-multiple-range-statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you can use `yield from` (python 3.5)

```
 def ranger():
     yield from range(1, 10)
     yield from range(20, 30)
     yield from range(50, 100)

 for x in ranger():
     print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `range` function returns a list. If you want a list of multiple ranges, you need to concatenate these lists. For example:

```
range(1, 5) + range(11, 15)
```

returns `[1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14]`

Comment: this doesn't work in Python3.x.
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'

Comment: @VladBezden: you are correct. This answer was specifically for Python 2, not Python 3. The proper way is in the accepted answer by @gunzapper. If you want a less neat way that looks more similar to mine, you'll want to convert the two ranges to lists first: `list(range(1, 5)) + list(range(11, 15))`

Answer (score 0):

Range module helps you to get numbers between the given input.

Syntax:

range(x) - returns list starting from 0 to x-1

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

range(x,y) - returns list starting from x to y-1

```
>>> range(10,20)
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>>
```

range(x,y,stepsize) - returns list starting from x to y-1 with stepsize

```
>>> range(10,20,2)
[10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3.x you can do:

```
output = [*range(1, 10), *range(20, 30)]
```

or using itertools.chain function:

```
from itertools import chain

data = [range(1, 10), range(20, 30)]
output = [*chain(*data)]
```

or using [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) function

```
from itertools import chain

data = [range(1, 10), range(20, 30)]
output = [*chain.from_iterable(data)]
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```